# Self-deleting program works fine in C but error in C++ project

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I need a way to self-delete the executable within my Win32 C++ project, and I found a program that does it in C:

selfdel.c:

```c
//  http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/self-deleting-executables
//  selfdel.c
//
//  Self deleting executable for Win9x/WinNT (works for all versions of windows)
//
//  J Brown 1/10/2003
//
//  This source file must be compiled with /GZ turned OFF
//  (basically, disable run-time stack checks)
//
//  Under debug build this is always on (MSVC6)
//
//
/**
 * The way this works is:
    * Firstly a child process is created in a suspended state (any process will do - i.e. explorer.exe).
    * Some code is then injected into the address-space of the child process.
    * The injected code waits for the parent-process to exit.
    * The parent-process is then deleted.
    * The injected code then calls ExitProcess, which terminates the child process.
*/
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)

#define CODESIZE 0x200

//
//  Structure to inject into remote process. Contains 
//  function pointers and code to execute.
//
typedef struct _SELFDEL
{
    struct _SELFDEL *Arg0;          // pointer to self

    BYTE    opCodes[CODESIZE];      // code 

    HANDLE  hParent;                // parent process handle

    FARPROC fnWaitForSingleObject;
    FARPROC fnCloseHandle;
    FARPROC fnDeleteFile;
    FARPROC fnSleep;
    FARPROC fnExitProcess;
    FARPROC fnRemoveDirectory;
    FARPROC fnGetLastError;

    BOOL    fRemDir;

    TCHAR   szFileName[MAX_PATH];   // file to delete

} SELFDEL;

#pragma pack(pop)

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define FUNC_ADDR(func) (PVOID)(*(DWORD *)((BYTE *)func + 1) + (DWORD)((BYTE *)func + 5))
#else
#define FUNC_ADDR(func) func
#endif

//
//  Routine to execute in remote process. 
//
static void remote_thread(SELFDEL *remote)
{
    // wait for parent process to terminate
    remote->fnWaitForSingleObject(remote->hParent, INFINITE);
    remote->fnCloseHandle(remote->hParent);

    // try to delete the executable file 
    while(!remote->fnDeleteFile(remote->szFileName))
    {
        // failed - try again in one second's time
        remote->fnSleep(1000);
    }

    // finished! exit so that we don't execute garbage code
    remote->fnExitProcess(0);
}

//
//  Delete currently running executable and exit
//  
BOOL SelfDelete(BOOL fRemoveDirectory)
{
    STARTUPINFO         si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    CONTEXT             context;
    DWORD               oldProt;
    SELFDEL             local;
    DWORD               entrypoint;

    TCHAR               szExe[MAX_PATH] = _T("explorer.exe");

    //
    //  Create executable suspended
    //
    if(CreateProcess(0, szExe, 0, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED|IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        local.fnWaitForSingleObject     = (FARPROC)WaitForSingleObject;
        local.fnCloseHandle             = (FARPROC)CloseHandle;
        local.fnDeleteFile              = (FARPROC)DeleteFile;
        local.fnSleep                   = (FARPROC)Sleep;
        local.fnExitProcess             = (FARPROC)ExitProcess;
        local.fnRemoveDirectory         = (FARPROC)RemoveDirectory;
        local.fnGetLastError            = (FARPROC)GetLastError;

        local.fRemDir                   = fRemoveDirectory;

        // Give remote process a copy of our own process handle
        DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentProcess(), 
            pi.hProcess, &local.hParent, 0, FALSE, 0);

        GetModuleFileName(0, local.szFileName, MAX_PATH);

        // copy in binary code
        memcpy(local.opCodes, FUNC_ADDR(remote_thread), CODESIZE);

        //
        // Allocate some space on process's stack and place
        // our SELFDEL structure there. Then set the instruction pointer 
        // to this location and let the process resume
        //
        context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER|CONTEXT_CONTROL;
        GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &context);

        // Allocate space on stack (aligned to cache-line boundary)
        entrypoint = (context.Esp - sizeof(SELFDEL)) & ~0x1F;
        
        //
        // Place a pointer to the structure at the bottom-of-stack 
        // this pointer is located in such a way that it becomes 
        // the remote_thread's first argument!!
        //
        local.Arg0 = (SELFDEL *)entrypoint;

        context.Esp = entrypoint - 4;   // create dummy return address
        context.Eip = entrypoint + 4;   // offset of opCodes within structure

        // copy in our code+data at the exe's entry-point
        VirtualProtectEx(pi.hProcess,   (PVOID)entrypoint, sizeof(local), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProt);
        WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)entrypoint, &local, sizeof(local), 0);

        FlushInstructionCache(pi.hProcess, (PVOID)entrypoint, sizeof(local));

        SetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &context);

        // Let the process continue
        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Compiling this alone using the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and `cl` creates an executable and it runs just as expected. Putting this in my C++ project creates an error within `remote_thread`:

[image: Error image in IDE]

I can't figure out this error. Building in x64 and x86 causes the same error. I have tried putting it in there just by itself, adding `extern "C" {}` as a wrapper, bringing the file in as a `.c` file and then linking with a header file, but then the header method broke all the other windows header files (probably because the compiler couldn't differentiate between c headers and cpp headers?) but that's besides the point, what am I missing here?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and C++ has much, much stricter typing rules.

Comment: I believe this is due C to interpreting `FARPROC` as a pointer to a function with an unspecified number of arguments while a C++ interprets the same definition as a pointer to a function with 0 arguments. Can you show us how `FARPROC` is defined? IIRC, it's somethings like `typedef int* (*FARPROC)()`.

Comment: @Brian is correct.  Try giving this file a `.c` extension (so that the compiler compiles it as C rather than C++).  The code you have posted is not valid C++ , because the function prototypes in `SELFDEL` don't have the correct number and type of parameters specified.

Comment: So then how do I use the function in my .c file in my C++?

Comment: If `FARPROC` is a macro, a first step is to look at pre-processor output.  @Brian is probably right.

Comment: You can declare `SelfDelete` as `extern "C" BOOL SelfDelete(BOOL fRemoveDirectory);` in your C++ code.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to declare it somehow in a header file?

Comment: Compile the C with a _C_ compiler into an object file and then import it to C++ as you would any other.  You'll need to add a header with the `extern C` declaration of your function.  nb: No way would I trust VC6 code from 2003 to do anything important.

Comment: You don't really need a header file, just put that declaration in your C++ file, somewhere before you actually call the function.

Comment: Wow that worked @Paul Sanders, thank you! Can I ask for an answer on why it does work?

Comment: @DaMahdi03 Done (I deleted my comment and posted a proper answer).  You can decide whether you prefer Remy's approach or mine.

Comment: @DaMahdi03 On a side note: see [Self-deleting Executables](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/self-deleting-executables#) for all kinds of different ways to accomplish this task. The approach your code is using is described as the last option at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Please do not paste pictures of plain text. Just copy&paste the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As covered in the comments, the problem here is the code is not valid when compiled as C++ because the function prototypes are incorrect.  You can force the compiler to compile the code as C by giving the file a `.c` suffix.

Your calling C++ code must then be informed the `SelfDelete` is a C function rather than a C++ function.  This is because C++ functions have [mangled names](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling) to allow for things like overloading.  You do this by declaring the function as `extern "C"` in your C++ code:

```
extern "C" BOOL SelfDelete(BOOL fRemoveDirectory);
```

Just put this in your calling C++ code, somewhere before you actually call the function.  Without this, your program will not link, because the C code and C++ code will disagree on what the function is actually called behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

`FARPROC` does not work the same way in C++ as it does in C.  This is actually described in the [`CallWindowProc` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowprocw):

> ...
> The `FARPROC` type is declared as follows:
>
> `int (FAR WINAPI * FARPROC) ()`
>
> In C, the `FARPROC` declaration indicates a callback function that has an unspecified parameter list. In C++, however, the empty parameter list in the declaration indicates that a function has no parameters. This subtle distinction can break careless code.
> ...

So, you will have to use proper function-pointer signatures instead, eg:

```cpp
typedef struct _SELFDEL
{
    ...
    DWORD (WINAPI *fnWaitForSingleObject)(HANDLE, DWORD);
    BOOL (WINAPI *fnCloseHandle)(HANDLE);
    BOOL (WINAPI *fnDeleteFile)(LPCTSTR);
    void (WINAPI *fnSleep)(DWORD);
    void (WINAPI *fnExitProcess)(UINT);
    BOOL (WINAPI *fnRemoveDirectory)(LPCTSTR);
    DWORD (WINAPI *fnGetLastError)();
    ...
} SELFDEL;
```

```cpp
SELFDEL local;
...
local.fnWaitForSingleObject     = &WaitForSingleObject;
local.fnCloseHandle             = &CloseHandle;
local.fnDeleteFile              = &DeleteFile;
local.fnSleep                   = &Sleep;
local.fnExitProcess             = &ExitProcess;
local.fnRemoveDirectory         = &RemoveDirectory;
local.fnGetLastError            = &GetLastError;
...
```

Comment: *"can break careless code"* - Nice find. It's rare that the official documentation is *this* explicit about the consequences of mindlessness.